# Shuffle optimization in the MapReduce framework

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, hadoop2

I'm looking for a research/implementation based project on Hadoop and I came across the list posted on the wiki page - http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ProjectSuggestions. But, this post is old. So, I'm not sure if some of these ideas have already been implemented or not. I was particularly interested in "Sort and Shuffle optimization in the MR framework". This can reduce seek work and intermediate storage".

Has anyone tried this before? Or any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Are you looking for ways to optimize your MR framework in the "Sort and Shuffle phase"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask; what *did* you find in your research?  For the benefit of others, the correct link is http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopResearchProjects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort and shuffle optimization in Hadoop MapReduce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085015/sort-and-shuffle-optimization-in-hadoop-mapreduce)

Comment: yes @VigneshI i am looking for ways to optimize the MR framework in general, not for a specific application.